# Отступы при создании canvas

Tags: canvas, pixijs

Использую pixi js

Хочу создать канвас в браузере, чтобы он был на весь экран.

Но, почему-то появляются небольшие отступы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
// Добавление канваса на html страницу
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
// ***
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было добавить стиль:

```
body {
    margin: 0; /* Убираем отступы */
}
```